# E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root? raspberry pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, directory, apt, dpkg

I am trying to install nginx in raspberry pi 3.
when I run "sudo apt-get update" command, I get the following error.

W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

I do not know what is an exact problem is.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error message could already explain what is the problem is

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory) 
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory) 
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (2: No such file or directory) 
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

The first three lines pop up when the corresponding directories are not existing or accessible (for reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031891/unable-to-read-etc-apt-apt-conf-d-directoryexists-2-no-such-file-or-direct

The last two lines pop up when the /var/lib/dpkg is not existing or accessible https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root.

In worst case you removed accidentally some important directories.

Another option is that the sudo did not work at all - then you would execute the command as unprivileged user and would end up with the error messages that you currently have.